# Can the following statements be proven in $Z$-Separation -Choice +Replacement?

Tags: set-theory, philosophy

Let $Z'$ be Zermelo set theory without Choice, and Separation replaced by Replacement.

Question 1:  Is Separation a theorem of $Z'$ (since classical logic is assumed, LEM holds)?

Question 2:  Is the following equivalence a theorem of $Z'$:  Choice $\equiv$ 'Every entire relation from $\mathrm A$ to $\mathrm B$ (where $\mathrm A$,$\mathrm B$ are classes and every element of $\mathrm A$ is related to at least one element of $\mathrm B$) contains (the graph of) a function $\mathrm A$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathrm B$'? (Note: the form of this equivalence is taken directly from the nLab entry "Choice Object".  Also, the Wikipedia article on Zermelo Set Theory suggests (in the subsection titled "The axiom of separation") that Zermelo's disposal of Russell's paradox in his system opens the door for talk of proper classes, and thus classes in general).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to question (1) is: yes, as long as there is a way to produce the empty set without using replacement, e.g. via a special axiom. You can separate any non-empty subset by taking an element from it, and replacing every element you want to remove from the larger set with that specified element.

For question (2), I think you need to be more precise with what a relation of classes is -- the equivalence holds if you restrict $A,B$ to be sets. (For one direction, well-order $B$ and map an element of $a$ to the $B$-least element to which it is related. The other way around: using the condition, it is trivial to construct sections to all surjections.)

Comment: Mees de Vries:  Very helpful, thanks.  Have you any suggestions on how to be more precise with what a relation of classes is?  As you are aware, LEM is equivalent to (in both $Z$ and $Z'$) {a$\neq$b} is choice.

Comment: No simple suggestions. If this were an external statement about classes you could work with formulas, but you're asking whether a theory proves that something is equivalent to a statement about *all* classes. You'd have to find a way to quantify over classes within the language of $Z'$, which is not obvious at all. I'm not sure what you mean by the last part, as I've never done constructive set theory.

Comment: You are also aware that Replacement implies transfinite recursion.  I am wondering whether one can use LEM and transfinite recursion to show that $Z'$ $\vdash$ Choice (with a proper definition of the notion 'relation of classes'--probably not, but then, what is the hidden asumption, if any, that relates Separation, Replacement, and Choice?).

Comment: @MeesdeVries. In the first-order language of set theory it is not possible to quantify over classes. A class $C$ is the same thing as a formula  $f$ (informally, a statement, with or without free variables).  Saying $x\in C$ is an abbreviation for $f[x].$   A quantifier $\forall$ or $\exists$ must be followed by a variable-symbol. There is no way to write  \exists f when f is a formula. In a specific case we may be able to define a class-function,  e.g. $f(x)=x+1$ for ordinal $x.$ But we can't say "$\exists f \;\forall x\in On\; f(x)=x+1)$.

Comment: @user254665, yes, I know, that is what I was getting at. I suppose it would be possible to define a logical language internally to ZFC, and quantifying over sets which satisfy some (internal) predicate? But, that is kind of beyond my expertise.

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin, I am still not quite sure what you are asking, but certainly $Z' \not \vdash AC$, as in fact $ZF \not \vdash AC$.

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin, What is asked is whether, in $Z'$, the statement AC is equiv. to :  For any  relation $R$ between any $A,  B$ with dom $(R)=A$  there is a function $f:A\to B$ where $f(a)=b\implies aRb$ for all $a\in A.$

Comment: @user25465:  Thanks for making the equivalence more precise.

Comment: Mees de Vries: Correct, but for Replacement, what allows the functions to which Replacement refers to exist?  What allows the $\varphi$(x) in Separation to hold?  Choice is related to these notions, but how? (Sorry if this is imprecise, but I think that in forming the notion $\varphi$, we implicitly use at least a weak form of choice (i.e. LEM).)

Comment: That is, user254665--sorry for the typo.

Comment: @MeesdeVries:  I am interested in the category-theoretic distinction between an 'external' theory of classes and an 'internal' theory of sets.  What is, in category theory, an 'external' theory of classes, and how does it relate (show via arrow diagrams) to an 'internal' theory of sets ($Z$, for example).  Please modify your answer with an addendum answering this question.  Thanks (it will be very much appreciated).